# Extract actions on different rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have the following data frame

```
    **column1      column2   column3   column4**  
0    person1       action1   action2   action3
1    person2       action1   action2   action3
2    person3       action1   action2   action3
3    person1       action1   action2   action3
4    person3       action1   action2   action3
5    person2       action1   action2   action3
.
.
.
n    person1      action1    action2   action3
```

What I want is to group by the different values of column1, and after that extract to data frame or to a txt file the sequence of action of each specific person

so I want to know that person1 at row0 execute some action. After that the person at row1 execute some other actions

I execute `gb = df.groupby('column1')` to group by the values of column1

How to extract the sequence of actions? Note that the data frame has thousands of rowS and I want to integrate all of them.

Thanks

Comment: You want one file per person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfs = {}

# for each person, save their actions to ...
for person, actions in df.groupby('column1'):
    dfs[person] = actions  # ... a dict of dataframes
    actions.to_csv(f'{person}.csv', index=False)  # ... a csv file
```

**Edit**: one action per row

```
# for each person, save their actions to ...
for person, actions in df.melt('column1')[['column1', 'value']].groupby('column1')):
    dfs[person] = actions  # ... a dict of dataframes
    actions.to_csv(f'{person}.csv', index=False)  # ... a csv file
```

Comment: thank you. Now I have in different csv files the actions of different persons

Comment: is it possible the CSV to entail the actions is order?fo example first this second this etc. Or 1: this action 2:this action?

Comment: So you want only one action per row?

Comment: i want the sequence of action on each row grouped by the persons. For example:

person1---first action: the value of culumn2, second action: the value of column3 third action: the value of column3

person1 (second row)----first action: the value of culumn2, second action: the value of column3 third action: the value of column3

etc

Comment: I'm sorry but it's unclear for me. Maybe you just want to sort your dataframe: `df.sort_values('column1')`.

Answer (score 0):

> ... group by the different values of column1, and after that extract to data frame

As you mentioned you have grouped by 'column1' - `gb = df.groupby('column1')`

Each group **is** a DataFrame:

- iterate over the groupby object - `gb` - it will produce (name,group) pairs
- create a dictionary using the name as the key and the group as the value.

  - {name:group, ...}

---

[Iterating through groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups)